# C++ Template recursive to check type in std::tuple

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, template-meta-programming

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename TupleType, typename T, std::size_t index = 0> constexpr std::size_t find_from(){
    if constexpr (index == std::tuple_size_v<TupleType>) return index;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<index, TupleType>, T>) return index;
    return find_from<TupleType, T, index+1>();
} 

int main(){
    std::cout << find_from<std::tuple<int,double>, int, 0>()<< std::endl;
}
```

I want to find the index of a type in a std::tuple, Why this code can't compile in mingw64-gcc? It seem to tell me template recursive is too deep. What's the right way to find a type index in std::tuple?
gcc version 7.2.0 ,compile with -std=c++17

Answer (score 4):

You need an `else` before the second condition and before the final `return`:

```
template<typename TupleType, typename T, std::size_t index = 0> 
constexpr std::size_t find_from()
{
    if constexpr (index == std::tuple_size_v<TupleType>) { return index; }
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::tuple_element_t<index, TupleType>, T>) { return index; } 
    else { return find_from<TupleType, T, index+1>(); }
}
```

Without the `else`, `find_from<TupleType, T, index+1>` will be always instantiated even if the previous conditions evaluated to `true`.

[**live example on wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jV4OgGmslObD3Q4c)

Comment: got it, I misunderstand compile time if

Comment: Is this code you provided in our answer public domain (in other words, there is absolutely no ownership such as copyright, trademark, or patent)? Or which restrictions do apply If I want to reuse your code snippet?