# Why does this get_index implementation fail on VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, c++17, variant

Barry gave us [this gorgeous `get_index` for variants](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52303687/560648):

```
template <typename> struct tag { };

template <typename T, typename V>
struct get_index;

template <typename T, typename... Ts> 
struct get_index<T, std::variant<Ts...>>
    : std::integral_constant<size_t, std::variant<tag<Ts>...>(tag<T>()).index()>
{ };
```

To be used as follows:

```
using V = variant<A, B, C>;
constexpr const size_t N = get_index<B, V>::value;  // 1
```

It works great in Clang (OSX).

But in Visual Studio 2017 [I'm getting](https://godbolt.org/z/aFFRNN) the following:

```
<source>(10): error C2039: 'index': is not a member of 'std::variant<tag<Ts>...>'
<source>(10): note: see declaration of 'std::variant<tag<Ts>...>'
<source>(11): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'get_index<T,std::variant<_Types...>>' being compiled
Compiler returned: 2
```

I can't see why. Any ideas?

*(Full disclosure: in my project I'm actually using [`mpark::variant`](https://github.com/mpark/variant) because I have been using Xcode 9, which didn't have `std::variant`. However, you can see from the Godbolt MCVE above that this affects the implementation with `std::variant` as well. I'm convinced the problem is either in the code above, or in the compiler.)*

Comment: Code is fine. Compiler bug.

Comment: Except that `get_index<B, V>::value` is 1.

Comment: One workaround is to ship the expression into a variable template.

Comment: @Barry That's a different error because `{}}` contains an unmatched `}`

Comment: I bet my 2 cents it's a bug. Anyway, I see that changing in `std::variant<tag<Ts>...>{tag<T>{}}.index()` (braces instead round parentheses) we get a different error: "<source>(12): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::variant<tag<Ts>...>' <source>(12): note: The target type has no constructors". Using the same contruct in other places (in `main()`, by example) gives no error.

Comment: @Oktalist Oooooooooooooooooooooooooooooops

Comment: @max66 Fair enough - good enough for an answer for me that

Comment: FWIW, [it works](https://godbolt.org/z/WLJSyC) if the expression is moved into a `constexpr` function of type `std::size_t()`, but not for a `constexpr auto` function (compiler nonsensically claims that the `auto` function is used before it is defined).

Comment: @ArneVogel Nice! I wonder whether that also might make a nice answer for posterity...

Comment: @ArneVogel - you should expand your comment in an answer, IMHO.

Comment: try to use `/Permissive-` flag since it changes the code path taken inside the compiler https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/two-phase-name-lookup-support-comes-to-msvc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bet my 2 cents that is a compiler bug.

I see that if I write in `main()`

```
std::cout << std::variant<tag<int>, tag<float>>{tag<float>{}}.index() << std::endl;
```

the compiler doesn't complain.

And doesn't complain also if I write a template function as follows

```
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
void foo ()
 { std::cout << std::variant<tag<Ts>...>(tag<T>{}).index() << std::endl; }
```

and I call it, from `main()`, with

```
foo<int, long, int, long long>();
```

No problem also declaring the following variable in `main()`

```
std::integral_constant<std::size_t, std::variant<tag<int>, tag<float>>(tag<float>{}).index()>  ic;
```

But if I change the `get_index` specialization as follows (using braces for initialization instead of round parentheses)

```
template <typename T, typename... Ts> 
struct get_index<T, std::variant<Ts...>>
    : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, std::variant<tag<Ts>...>{tag<T>()}.index()>
 { };
```

the compiler complain but with a different error

> example.cpp
>
> (12): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'std::variant...>'
>
> (12): note: The target type has no constructors
>
> (13): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'get_index>' being compiled
>
> Compiler returned: 2

Seems that, for reasons I can't understand, the compiler doesn't see `std::variant<tag<Ts>...>`, inside `get_index`, as a `std::variant` with all it's methods.

Comment: Agreed. I had to fallback on the `if constexpr` chain from another answer on the original question. Sorry Barry!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - it's a pity because the Barry's solution is really simple and elegant.

Comment: Indeed! Although come to think of it I do think the conditionals one is easier to follow.