# Is it possible to get the index of a variant as a constexpr variable?

Tags: c++, switch-statement, c++17, constexpr, variant

I have the following code ([play with example](https://godbolt.org/z/qsYmTv)). It checks what the underlying value of a [variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is and receives this underlying value using [get](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/get). As you can see the code gets quite repetitive.

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, double, std::string> v;
    // v holds a string
    v = "hi there!";

    switch(v.index()) {
        case 0: 
            {   // brackets to avoid cross initialization
                int i = std::get<int>(v);
                // handle int
            }    
            break;
        case 1: 
            {
                double d = std::get<double>(v);
                // handle double
            }
            break;
        case 2: 
            {
                std::string s = std::get<std::string>(v);
                // handle string
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is there some way to get the index of a variant as a `constexpr` variable? I would like to do something like this:

```
// what I would like to do
// auto val_of_v = std::get<v.index()>(v);

// Error: template argument deduction/substitution failed
//        in 'constexpr' expansion of v<...>::index()
```

**Related Post:** [Get index by type in std::variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52303316/get-index-by-type-in-stdvariant).

Comment: If the variable is not constexpr, then the type it holds can't be known at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only if the variant is constexpr itself:

```
constexpr std::variant<int, double> v{24};
auto a = std::get<v.index()>(v);
```

Otherwise the information can only be known at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit), which is the library facility that implements that switch for you:

```
std::variant<int, double, std::string> v;
// v holds a string
v = "hi there!";

std::visit([](auto&& x){
    // x is whatever the variant was holding (could be int, double, or string)
}, v);
```